# How to implement a transaction and account system in Django?

Tags: python, django, web

I am building a personal finance app that stores transactions and accounts. Each transaction will affect the balance of the account. How would I implement this in my app? I haven't found a specific answer despite searching the internet for a while.

models.py

```
class Account(models.Model):
    DateCreated = models.DateTimeField()
    AccountName = models.SlugField(max_length= 100, primary_key=True)
    UserID = models.ForeignKey(MyUser, on_delete=models.CASCADE)      
    Type = models.CharField(max_length= 20)
    Balance = models.DecimalField(max_digits=19, decimal_places=8)
    Value = models.DecimalField(max_digits=19, decimal_places=8)

class Transaction(models.Model):

    TypeChoices = (
                    ('Income', 'Income'),
                    ('Expense', 'Expense'),
                    ('Transfer', 'Transfer'),
                    )

    CategoryChoices = (
                        ('Rent', 'Rent'),
                        ('Utilities', 'Utilities'),
                        ('Food', 'Food'),
                        ('Leisure', 'Leisure'),
                        ('Insurance', 'Insurance'),
                        ('Gas', 'Gas'),
                        ('Savings', 'Savings'),
                        ('Investment', 'Investment'),
                        ('Phone Payment', 'Phone Payment'),
                        ('Gym Payment','Gym Payment'),
                        ('Salary', 'Salary'),
                        ('Asset', 'Asset'),
                        ('Miscellaneous', 'Miscellaneous'),
                        ('Transfer', 'Transfer'),
                        )

    AccountName = models.ForeignKey(Account, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    UserID = models.ForeignKey(MyUser, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    Date = models.DateField()
    Type = models.CharField(max_length = 8, choices = TypeChoices)
    Entity = models.CharField(max_length = 100)
    Description = models.CharField(max_length = 200)
    BudgetType = models.CharField(max_length = 20, choices = CategoryChoices)
    Amount = models.DecimalField(max_digits=19, decimal_places=8)
```

I currently have created views that will allow the user to create, update, and delete transactions and accounts, but do not have the transactions affecting the balances of the account. What is the best way to implement this?

Comment: Maybe you can change the user's balance in your model's `save()` method?

Comment: I think that could be an answer.. So maybe I could use aggregate sum() to sum the transactions and save the balance that way?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use below code in Transaction model
(I tested it)

```
def save(self, *args, **kwargs):
       self.AccountName.Balance += self.Amount
       self.AccountName.save()
       super(Transaction, self).save(*args, **kwargs) # Call the real save() method
```

This function will reduce the amount from balance before deleting the object.

```
def delete(self, *args, **kwargs):
       self.AccountName.Balance -= self.Amount
       self.AccountName.save()
       super(Transaction, self).delete(*args, **kwargs)
```

if you want change balance after updating amount you can use below signal:

```
@receiver(pre_save, sender=Transaction)
def update_balance_account(sender, instance, update_fields=None, **kwargs):
    trans = Transaction.objects.get(AccountName=instance.AccountName, id=instance.id, UserID=instance.UserID)
    instance.AccountName.Balance -= trans.Amount
    instance.AccountName.save()
```

Comment: Thank you, that's a helpful start! That works for adding the transaction to the account balance, but won't update the account when the transaction is removed.

Comment: you can overloaded another method or create a signal post_delete
Don't worry i will help you

Comment: Ok thanks! I am currently trying to overwrite the save method in the Account model. Then aggregate(sum('Amount')) of each transaction, so that way the account will be the result of the sums of the transactions. That way the account will be correct for transactions adds, deletes, and updates. Is this the right approach?

Comment: I don't think it would be appropriate

if you wanna change balance after update amount you can write a pre_save method for Transaction

Comment: Ok so the pre_save works on existing transactions, but when I create a new transaction, I get an error that "Transaction matching query does not exist." It is reflected in the Account balance but does not save the transaction.

Comment: Never mind I figured it out. Basically python wasn't able to determine if a new instance was being created. Adding a simple if statement to the update_balance_account works! Add this: if not instance._state.adding: then the rest of the code.

Comment: Also thank you for all of your help! I am knew to Django and this helped me learn a bit about signals and how to implement them. Appreciate it!